# Use two NICs for different subnets

Tags: linux, ip, routing, network-interface

In my office I have use a system with two network cards. I want to use both at same time. I have four subnets in my LAN.

I want to route two subnets (192.168.2.0 and 192.168.4.0) through eth0
and another two subnets (192.168.3.0 and 192.168.5.0) through eth1.
I want use both in parallel

Comment: In that case you just need to assign 2 ip on each interface, 

e.g. if you set the IP's 
`192.168.2.1/24` & `192.168.4.0/24` for `eth0` & 
`192.168.3.1/24` & `192.168.5.0/24` for `eth1`

Comment: It's not work for me. I am unable to communicate 1st NIC to 2nd NIC.

If I am giving 192.168.3.10 1st NIC & 192.168.5.10 to 2nd NIC. Then I am unable to ping 1st to 2nd & 2nd to 1st.

Please suggest......................

Comment: As suggested by Rabin, you need to assign 2 IP Address on each interface. I think [this](http://oclc.org/support/services/ezproxy/documentation/technote/2l.en.html) document will tell you how to do in detail.

Comment: My question is, How to use both NIC parallels. I want to use both traffic at same time

Comment: Do you use Network Manager ? which distro are you using ?

Comment: I am suing both NIC on My Linux Squid proxy Server. I have two ISP & want to use on a single machine with two Network Card. But at same time only single Lan card is working. I want to use both Network card parallaly 1st NIC to 1st ISP & 2nd NIC for 2nd ISP. IS that possible or not in Linux Centos 6....................

Comment: That is probably because you have only a single GW which is your default GW. you can change your routing table to be SRC routing, so SUBNET 1&3 will go though ISP1 and SUBNET 2&4 though ISP2. you can find more information about the on http://www.lartc.org/lartc.html#LARTC.RPDB.MULTIPLE-LINKS

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have suggested, you can add an IP address for each network to the respective devices. Not knowing your system but assuming it is a modern Linux you should be able to issue the following:

```
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.4.1/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.3.1/24 dev eth1
ip addr add 192.168.5.1/24 dev eth1
```

This will set up routes for each of those subnets so that packets destined for 192.168.3.100 for example, will be routed through eth1. It is important to use the correct network mask of /24 and use distinct subnets to obtain this behavior.

This will allow you to use them "in parallel" depending on the destination address. To actually have data come in on one address, say 192.168.3.1 and go out on another, say 192.168.2.1, then you are effectively becoming a router and need to read up on IP forwarding and general routing concepts, and probably implement a firewall also.

**Additionally** (since reading your comment)

If you want to balance your connection over the links then you could [use multiple routing tables](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) which still only requires iproute2, which provides the *ip* command above.